# styling problems with IE

Tags: html, css

I am new to this so. It is probably the basic stuff...I have problem with IE, it does not render web page as chrome and FF does. Those three boxes, boxleft, boxcenter and boxright odes not appear in line. last one, box out seems like drops down just beneath boxcenter. I try to find the answer but no luck. here is the html and css. any kind of help are very welcome. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css" />
      <!--[if IE 6]>
      <link href="default_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <![endif]-->
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header" class="container">
         <div id="logo">
            <img src="layout/img.png" width="415" height="90" alt="img" />
         </div>
         <!--END LOGO-->
         <div id="mainmenu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
            <ul>
         </div>
         <!--END MAIN MENU-->
      </div>
      <!--END HEADER-->
      <div id="mainmiddle" class="container"></div>
      <!--END MAIN-MIDDLE SECTION-->
      <div id="bottomsection" class="container">
         <div id="bottomsectionName">
            <p>PRODUCTS:</p>
         </div>
         <!-- END BOTTOM SECTION NAME-->
         <div id="boxholder">
            <div id="boxLeft">
               <div class="label">
                  <p>
                     <a href="#">text
                     <a>
                  </p>
               </div>
               <!--END LABEL-->
               <img src="layout/products.jpg" width="312" height="157" alt="" />
            </div>
            <!--END BOX LEFT-->
            <div id="boxRight">
            <div class="label">
            <p><a href="#">exclusive</a></p>
            </div><!--END LABEL-->
            <img src="layout/products.jpg" width="312" height="157" alt="" />
            </div><!--END BOX RIGHT-->
            <div id="boxCenter">
               <div class="label">
                  <p><a href="#">frost</a></p>
               </div>
               <!--END LABEL-->
               <img src="layout/products.jpg" width="312" height="157" alt="" />
            </div>
            <!--END BOX CENTER-->
         </div>
         <!--END BOX HOLDER-->
      </div>
      <!-- END BOTTOM SECTION-->
      <div id="info" class="container">
         <div id="infoboxLeft"  class="infotext"></div>
         <!-- END INFO BOX LEFT-->
         <div id="infoboxRight" class="infotext">
            <p>info:<br />Address: </p>
         </div>
         <!-- END INFO BOX RIGHT-->
      </div>
      <!--END INFO SECTION-->
      <div id="footer">
         <p>Copyright: </p>
      </div>
      <!--END FOOTER-->
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
#header
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#logo
{
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0px, 0px, 0px, 0px;
}
#logo img
{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#mainmenu
{
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#mainmenu ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
#mainmenu ul li
{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-top: -2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#mainmenu ul li a
{
    color: #c93159;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mainmenu ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mainmiddle
{
    background: url(layout/norway.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 400px;
}
#bottomsection
{
    height: 185px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
#bottomsectionName
{
    height: 28px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#bottomsectionName p
{
    color: 000000;
    float: right;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
#boxholder
{
    height: 157px;
}
.label
{
    background-color: #c93159;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 104px;
    margin-top: 109px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 208px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.label p
{
    color: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-right: 7px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.label p a
{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
#boxLeft
{
    float: left;
    height: 157px;
    width: 312px;
}
#boxCenter
{
    height: 157px;
    margin-left: 324px;
    width: 312px;
}
#boxRight
{
    float: right;
    height: 157px;
    width: 312px;
}
.infotext
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 0.667em;
}
#info
{
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px, 0px,0px,0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#infoboxLeft
{
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 480px;
}
#infoboxRight
{
    float: right;
    height: 150px;
    width: 480px;
}
#infoboxRight p
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 110px;
    text-align: right;
}
#footer
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
#footer p
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 0.667em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your HTML code? it is not readable.

Comment: Web Developers will often check to see what browser the user is using, and write parts of the code specific to that browser. There are many idiosyncrasies between browsers, so the different browsers often do not render the same page identically. Unfortunately there isn't always a one size fits all solution like in other languages. I hope this helps.

Comment: Which version(s) of IE?

Comment: I am guessing it's IE6

Comment: ok, I will better format the HTML soon. it is ie8.

Comment: also, what I noticed is that IE has added one more label form my html/css...and I have edited if statement for all ie..

Comment: I we got it! at least one part. so after edited if statement in head. I had to change style of all boxes. What I did is, for #boxleft:margin-left:0px; deleted float, #boxright:margin-left:12px; and for #boxholder I added position:absolute; now all stands where I wanted. But still have one extra label to far left side, even outside container....

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to write IE specific CSS. My suggestion would be to do it using conditional comments like this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
.container
{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
}
#header
{
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 180px;
overflow: hidden;
}
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 6]>
My page's CSS goes here
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
My page's CSS goes here
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
My page's CSS goes here
<![endif]-->
```

You can use these types of if statements to set your CSS for specific versions of IE. You'll have to adjust the values in each one and test in IE to get it to look how you want it. This will not affect how it appears in other browsers. Also you don't have to put all of your page's CSS inside these comments, just what isn't displaying correctly in IE.

Comment: Thanks. I somehow menage make it works. It just one more bug left to fix. It seems that IE8 in my case, somehow display more classes then I specify. references to code it is label class. It put 4th along side those 3 that I specified.